# Level of entropy in full disk encryption

Tags: encryption

I would like to know how high the level of entropy is when installing Ubuntu and encrypting the installation. As far as I know, the only partition that is not encrypted is the /boot partition because it has the boot loader unencrypted. When I use TrueCrypt to encrypt Windows, I am asked to move the mouse cursor inside the window to create a pool to improve the level of entropy.

As Ubuntu does not offer something like that, how can I be sure the keys, salts etc. are secure enough?

Comment: Interesting question, +1!. If you don't get an answer after a few days you could try reasking on [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Please make sure to follow [these guidelines](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1480/cross-posting-questions-that-are-on-topic-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites) on cross-posting, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you might not be asked to move your mouse, it will still help build entropy/feed your random number generator.

In Linux, `/dev/random` is your PRNG.  `/dev/urandom` is fed by `/dev/random`, but provides more raw data to use.

Accessing data on HDDs, moving the mouse and typing are all actions that will help feed your random number generator.

Unfortunately, when you're in Ubuntu's LiveCD mode, you most likely will not have many things to do that might cause increases in entropy generation.

You can, however, rest easy and know that random number generation in Linux has been under peer review and should be safe.  If you can't accept this for yourself, you're more than welcome to check out the [kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux).

Comment: Do you know at which point in the installation process the entropy starts being generated from mouse movements and at which point it starts being used for encryption? So that we know when we should move the mouse cursor.

Comment: No, but typically you can (and likely should) re-generate any keys after you've confirmed proper entropy.  [For example, your `sshd` keys.](https://serverfault.com/questions/471327/how-to-change-a-ssh-host-key)

Answer (score 0):

As of Ubuntu 22.04.2 (or as of default kernel version 5.15.0-47), the Linux Random system underwent a major revision, which has drastically reduced the size of the entropy pool.

Rest assured that the encryption keys during installation are strong enough - and even more so with the latest revisions to Random.

See [this Q&A for more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427470/entropy-is-stuck-at-256-after-upgrading-to-kernel-5-15-0-47).