# Entropy is stuck at 256 after upgrading to Kernel 5.15.0-47

Tags: server, 22.04

After upgrading to Kernel 5.15.0-47 on Ubuntu 22.04 Server, I've noticed that my available entropy has dropped from the 3000-3500 range to a permanent value of 256.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
256
```

Is this normal, and what is the explanation of this sudden change?

Comment: It seems related to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704737/kernel-5-10-119-caused-the-values-of-proc-sys-kernel-random-entropy-avail-and-p), so maybe it's a feature that gets rolled out over LTS kernels also??

Comment: Finally I have been able to find more explanation on what happened. You can read commit message from Kernel.org explaining situation: * https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220522214457.37108-1-Jason@zx2c4.com/T/#u * https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ac2ab99072cce553c78f326ea22d72856f570d88
* https://www.theregister.com/2022/03/21/new_linux_kernel_has_improved/
* https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.18#Security

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears there was a [large commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/?h=linux-5.15.y&ofs=3200) in mainline kernel version 5.15.44 by Jason A. Donenfeld that did a lot of things to the Random system in the Linux kernel.

One of the results of this is that the overall entropy pool size has been reduced to 256 instead of 4096 like it was before:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize
256
```

It also appears this has been a discussion for other distros at some point in the lifespan when this patch hit the kernel ([here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/low-entropy-on-my-system/119233) and [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8730044.html?sid=da00c002b51aef95e30c65bb8f7cba4b)).