# Why no focal HWE kernel update in over a month?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, updates

My focal machines have been running the 5.15.0.**46**.49~20.04.16 version of `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` since approximately August 10th.

```
-Boots due to kernel updates-
Wed Aug 10 06:55        : 5.15.0-46-generi
Mon Aug 1 14:33         : 5.15.0-43-generi
Wed Jul 13 09:13        : 5.15.0-41-generi
Thu Jun 30 19:12        : 5.13.0-52-generi
Thu Jun 16 09:47        : 5.13.0-51-generi
Sun Jun 12 19:20        : 5.13.0-48-generi
Mon May 23 19:01        : 5.13.0-44-generi
Wed May 11 06:57        : 5.13.0-41-generi
Wed Apr 20 07:07        : 5.13.0-40-generi
Tue Mar 29 17:20        : 5.13.0-39-generi
Mon Mar 21 14:48        : 5.13.0-37-generi
Wed Mar 9 06:21         : 5.13.0-35-generi
Thu Feb 17 15:06        : 5.13.0-30-generi
Mon Jan 31 17:25        : 5.13.0-28-generi
Tue Jan 18 14:53        : 5.13.0-27-generi
Tue Jan 18 13:18        : 5.13.0-25-generi
Mon Jan 10 15:15        : 5.11.0-46-generi
Tue Jan 4 14:32         : 5.11.0-44-generi
Wed Dec 15 21:01        : 5.11.0-43-generi
Mon Nov 29 17:10        : 5.11.0-41-generi
Mon Nov 8 20:38         : 5.11.0-40-generi
Sun Oct 24 12:15        : 5.11.0-38-generi
Tue Oct 19 06:59        : 5.4.0-89-generic
```

A 5.15.0.**48**.54~20.04.18 version has been in 'proposed' for a long time, weeks at least.

While I like not rebooting my server, I'm curious as to why this long delay between kernel updates.  More generally, is there a site where I can read about this sort of thing so I don't have to ask specific questions here?

Comment: There is no such site AFAIK. It is up to maintainers when they decide to bumb a new kernel. It depends mostly on upstream commits.

Comment: Whilst it's not kernel specific... https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/focal-changes  for the ML post of changes maybe... though it's reposted (combined with others) in places like UWN (see `linux-meta-hwe-5.15 5.15.0.48.54~20.04.18` listed in issue 752 of last week; https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue752)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HWE kernel version follows the latest kernel patches - in this case the HWE-20.04 follows the 22.04 kernel line (kernel 5.15.0).

The last security patch was `5.15.0-46`, while `-47` was a huge backport release, with lots of minor (and some major) fixes and tweaks (with one of the larger changes being to the [random system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427470/entropy-is-stuck-at-256-after-upgrading-to-kernel-5-15-0-47)).

I believe the developers have thought that a separate `-47` release for the HWE line was not a priority, and has pushed those changes to the next `-48` release.

I have created [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428255/how-do-i-see-which-kernel-patches-are-included-in-an-ubuntu-kernel-image) where it is explained how you can see in a simple way which patches are included in each kernel release.